# PHP Change Background Image Everyday Based on Day from Database

Tags: php

I have an PHP code to set daily background page change(everyday change based on day name from database)

On my table

```
BACKGROUND_DAY | BACKGROUND_IMAGE
Monday         | White.png
Tuesday        | Black.png
Wednesday      | Yellow.png
\\until Sunday
```

Then I query it:

```
$day = date("l");

$qBackground = oci_parse($c1, "SELECT * FROM WA_GA_TBL_BACKGROUNDS");
oci_execute($qBackground);
while($dBackground = oci_fetch_array($qBackground))
{
   $backgroundDayArray[] = $dBackground['BACKGROUND_DAY'];
   $backgroundImageArray[] = $dBackground['BACKGROUND_IMAGE'];
}

//print_r backgroundDayArray
Array ( [0] => Saturday [1] => Wednesday [2] => Friday [3] => Tuesday [4] => Thursday [5] => Monday [6] => Sunday ) 

$bg_color =  isset($backgroundImageArray[$day]) ? $backgroundImageArray[$day] : 'black';
```

and set it to HTML

```
<style>
html
{
    background: url(assets/img/background/<?php echo $bg_color; ?>) no-
    repeat center center fixed;
}
</style>
```

And the result is the page is show nothing.

What I want is,

Set the background image based on table day. If today is Monday then set it to background image for Monday.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to even have a while loop here.  When you query your database pass the current date in your query using PHP's `date('l')`.  This would dynamically get the color for the current date.

```
$day = date('l'); 
$query = "select BACKGROUND_IMAGE from WA_GA_TBL_BACKGROUNDS where BACKGROUND_DAY = $day";
```

Make sure the page where you have echo the current background image has a `.php` extension.  Also make sure the path exists.

Comment: My pleasure :).

Answer (score 0):

`$backgroundImageArray` is an associative array which has `int`s as keys. Thus, `$backgroundImageArray[$day]` will always be unset and your condition will result in `black`.
`print_r($backgroundImageArray)` will give you the hint.
In your while-loop, replace the array statements with

```
$backgroundImageArray[$dBackground['BACKGROUND_DAY']] = $dBackground['BACKGROUND_IMAGE'];
```

and it should work.